# Is online dating unsafe?

Tags: safety, internet

Is there any evidence to support the common conception that one is more likely to be physically injured when dating someone met online as opposed to someone met "offline"?

Comment: "Actual and perceived risk of victimization as a result of engaging in on-line relationships has as yet to be
systematically investigated." - [YOU'VE GOT MAIL! YOU DON'T WANT IT: CYBER-VICTIMIZATION AND ON-LINE DATING](http://www.albany.edu/scj/jcjpc/vol9is1/jerin.pdf), 2001. Anything since then?

Comment: Allegedly millenials don't know how to date w/o Tinder, so it would be hard to find a control group ;-)